# Connect to hbase from remote machine

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I have VM where  habse is installed.
IP:192.168.20.10
I want to try to connect to hbase from my desktop:
Here is what I am trying>

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/META-INF/spring/hbase-beans.xml", HBaseConnection.class);
    context.registerShutdownHook();
            UserRepository userRepository = context.getBean(UserRepository.class);
    List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();

    System.out.println("Number of users = " + users.size());
    System.out.println(users);
}






public List<User> findAll() {
        return hbaseTemplate.find(tableName, "cfInfo", new RowMapper<User>() {

            public User mapRow(Result result, int rowNum) throws Exception {
                return new User(Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO, qUser)), 
                                Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO, qEmail)),
                                Bytes.toString(result.getValue(CF_INFO, qPassword))

                                );
            }
        });

    }
```

And this is my bean.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:hadoop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop" xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
    xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop http://www.springframework.org/schema/hadoop/spring-hadoop.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hbase.dao"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.hbase.object"/>

     <hadoop:configuration id="hadoopConfiguration">fs.default.name=hdfs://192.168.20.10:9000</hadoop:configuration>


    <hadoop:hbase-configuration configuration-ref="hadoopConfiguration" zk-port="2181" zk-quorum="192.168.20.10"></hadoop:hbase-configuration>

    <bean id="hbaseTemplate" class="org.springframework.data.hadoop.hbase.HbaseTemplate">
        <property name="configuration" ref="hbaseConfiguration" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

This code works fine when I run directly in remote machine.When I am running same code from my windows machine by providing ip of hbase .,it doesnot return any value.

Comment: Are you able to ping your VM ip address from your host machine? Also are you able to telnet to the ZooKeeper and Hadoop ports from your host machine. This may be just an issue with network connection rather than a hbase issue

Answer (score 0):

> Configure your windows machine  `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`
>   file to resolve your HBase cluster node details. Recommended Make sure
>   DNS configuration is right!. i.e. addresses of all
>   nodes(Regionservers) of HBase Cluster is resolved from windows
>   machine.